# How can I determine the length of a row of integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to create a known dice game.

One part of it is to roll – with 5 dice – four consecutive numbers. With a common dice representing the numbers 1-6, the possibilities would only be:

- 1-2-3-4-X
- 2-3-4-5-X
- 3-4-5-6-X

I am storing the outcome of the 5 dice in an array, so I want to create a method to check if the integers stored in the array can create a row of at least 4 consecutive integers.

My first thought was something like this:

```java
public static boolean checkArr(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i+1] == arr[i]++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is not working because `arr[i+1]` is out of bounds for the last index.
How can I make it work?

Comment: For clarification, it appears you are using the word “row” to describe a sequence of contiguous int values.  Is that correct?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt to show us.

Comment: You have to sort the array to find consecutive values.  Loop through the array once, from zero to length - 2, comparing two values.  if value[index] == value[index + 1] + 1, increment a counter.  Return true if the counter >= 4.

Comment: Does the incrementing sequence have to be there before or after sorting for the condition to be true? Or just anywhere? Would you consider 6, 7, 8, 9 a sequence if the array contained 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9?

Comment: As for your problem, is it *only* for the number `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`? Or any sequence of four numbers which are contiguous?

Comment: @VGR Yes thats correct. With the word "row" I mean a sequence of contiguous int values.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  No, for any given sequence of integer values. My code is a bit messy so I just used an example array in my question.

Comment: If the array was `{4,3,1,7,8,9,6}`, would `6,7,8,9` still be "the row"? (I ask because you said you sorted them, which destroys any ordering of the original array).

Comment: @Andy Turner Yes, I will edit the question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: If you’re not required to do it completely "by hand", one may use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) and it [`nextSetBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit(int)) and `nextClearBit` methods. We’d still need an algorithm, but we would not need sorting first, and duplicates would be ignored automatically.

Comment: [My code using `BitSet` running online](https://rextester.com/DURW40957). If you need to allow duplicate entries (which you will typically have from rolling a dice), I recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be your solution.

```
 public static boolean findConsecutiveDice(int[] arr) {
    int streak = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length-1 ; i++ ){

        if (arr[i+1]  == arr[i] + 1  ){
            streak++;
        }

        else if (streak>1 && arr[i+1]  != arr[i] + 1  ){
            streak = 1;
        }
        if (streak == 4){
            return true;
        }
}
    return false;
}
```

I have tested some cases and it worked perfectly but u should test as well.

Comment: actually else if statement is important. If you remove that part. It will detect not Consecutive dice. And if it worked if u approve or upvote it will be appreciated.

Comment: Ehm yea I realized that because 1 2 3 5 6 would actually return true aswell. But else statement instead of else if should work aswell because its just the opposite right.

Also I tried to upvote your answer but apparently I need more reputation to upvote.

Comment: Can u approve the answer or not? If you cant it's okay buddy. Have a good day. I am happy to help. And if your question is already closed. It will not be changed if you edit. You have to ask another question

Comment: You could make this answer better by explaining why OP had problems with their approach, and why the changes you have made do what is required.

Comment: One, I would love some explanation to be added to the answer. What failed in to OP’s code and what changes were made and how they fixed it. Two, your code returns `true` for [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]. A bit to my surprise it returned `false` for [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ] and for [ 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 ].

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right but the problem is when I answered the question there were no code pieces provided by the Sogaria. That's why I didn't explains the problem with their approach and what I made the changes :D

Comment: @OleV.V. before the question was not updated. Sogaria was asking for ascending consecutive integers. That's why I did not take into account the [5,4,3,2] case. The [2,3,3,4,4,5] case should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or simply:

```
public static boolean checkArr(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i-1] + 1) {
            ++counter;
        } else if (arr[i] != arr[i-1]) {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    return counter >= 4;
}
```

UPDATE following @AndyTurner's comment:

```
public static boolean checkArr(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i-1] + 1) {
            ++counter;
            if (counter == 4) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (arr[i] != arr[i-1]) {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which is not very different from @egemenakturk's solution.

Comment: This only works if the _last_ consecutive run has length 4 or more. Otherwise, the counter will be reset.

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right.